# Redeployment on surge

Tags: deployment, surge.sh

I had redeployed my site on search but when I navigate to the URL the page is blank and I am getting this error:

```
(Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of :text/jsx:. Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.).
```

The command that I used for updating is :

`surge --domain asad-react-projects.surge.sh`

And in terminal it says successfully deployed.